# How to manipulate SVG nodes with javascript so that it would work in MS Edge?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, microsoft-edge

I have an `svg` element with `linearGradient` inside. At some point, I need to change the gradient colors so I do it like this:

```
var stops = [];
for (var i in description) {
    stops.push('<stop offset="' + i + '" stop-color="' + description[i] + '"/>');
}
var colorBar = svg.getElementById('colorMapGradient');
colorBar.innerHTML = stops.join('');
```

It works pretty fine in FF and Chrome, but doesn't change a thing when my page is loaded in Edge. When I debug it in that browser, I see no properties of the `colorBar` object, including `innerHtml`, as if it's not an ordinary HTML node (I guess it is). However, a usual set of properties is visible in other browsers.
So is there any workaround to set color stops to a `linearGradient` in Edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson), I got it working by accessing DOM from javascript:

```
            var colorBar = svg.getElementById('colorMapGradient');
            while (colorBar.firstChild) {
                colorBar.removeChild(colorBar.firstChild);
            }
            for (var i in description) {
                var stopNode = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'stop');
                stopNode.setAttribute('offset', i);
                stopNode.setAttribute('stop-color', description[i]);
                colorBar.appendChild(stopNode);
            }
```